# Create an array from multiple rows in a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a rather large mysql table that has the following structure:

```
fieldid | recordid | content
----------------------------
 10     |   01     | Google
 10     |   02     | Yahoo
 10     |   03     | Facebook
 20     |   01     | google.com
 20     |   02     | yahoo.com
 20     |   03     | facebook.com
 30     |   01     | Big search engine
 30     |   02     | Other search engine
 30     |   03     | Largest Social Network
 40     |   01     | Search engine
 40     |   02     | Search engine
 40     |   03     | Social Network
```

Where fieldid is the id for the field (in this case '10 is the 'site name', '20' is the 'site url', '30' is the 'site description' and '40' is the 'category').
Also, recordid is the id for all the fields in a given website (in this case 01 is Google, 02 is Yahoo and 03 is Facebook).

I would like to combine them into the equivalent of a result set (associative array) filtered by a particular 'category' such as:

```
site            |     url            |     description
----------------|------------------------------------------
Google          | google.com         | Big search engine
Yahoo           | yahoo.com          | Other search engine
```

Where in this case they are filtered by "Search engine".

I tried

```
SELECT
recordid,
GROUP_CONCAT( if( fieldID = 10, content, NULL ) ) AS 'site',
GROUP_CONCAT( if( fieldID = 20, content, NULL ) ) AS 'url',
GROUP_CONCAT( if( fieldID = 30, content, NULL ) ) AS 'description',
GROUP_CONCAT( if( fieldID = 40 and content = 'Search engine', content, NULL ) ) AS 'category'
FROM my_table
GROUP BY recordid
HAVING Category IS NOT NULL
```

Now, although this works, it is very, very slow because there are far more fieldids than the ones I need to process.  Does anyone know of a better way to achieve the same result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All different fieldids could be columns in your main table with names like site, url, description and so on, making your query very fast and easy with a simple group by. Dbs with EAV model can't be as efficient as normalized ones, you really need a serious reason to use EAV, are you fully aware of it?

Comment: A normalized table would be ideal, but unfortunately I have no control over the table itself (which already exists).  I am 'stuck' with this EAV model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use cascading self joins. Something like:

```
SELECT t.content AS 'Site', t2.content AS 'URL', t3.content AS 'Description', t4.content AS 'Category'
FROM my_table AS t
LEFT JOIN my_table AS t2 ON (t2.recordid = t.recordid AND t2.fieldid = 20)
LEFT JOIN my_table AS t3 ON (t3.recordid = t.recordid AND t3.fieldid = 30)
LEFT JOIN my_table AS t4 ON (t4.recordid = t.recordid AND t4.fieldid = 40 AND t4.content = 'Search engine')
WHERE t.fieldid = 10
```

Since the `WHERE` condition is going to significantly reduce the resultset, the query should perform faster, assuming you have appropriate indexes on `(fieldid)` and `(fieldid, recordid)`.